# Processing error occurred

Tags: systemd

When trying to retrieve References for 'Reference_ID_Type'='Request_for_Quote_ID', Workday throws the following error:

*[SOAP-ENV:Server.processingError] Processing error occurred. Can't get all instances of class:Request_for_Quote--IS

The Reference_ID_Type is valid according to the documentation:
https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Integrations/v41.2/Get_References.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.